# What type of data can you put into HDFS

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I just finished installing Hadoop. I am downloading from the internet data samples.

What types of data can I put into HDFS? For example, can I put Excel sheets?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put any type of data you wish on HDFS (including Excel sheets). However, you may not be able to read them.

For instance, unless there exists an HDFS connector on excel, you won't be able to open your files on the cluster and will have to copy them back on your machine.

If you want to read data from an excel sheet, the easiest way would be to export each sheet as a csv and read them on HDFS via hive, since there are multiple excel-compatible ODBC drivers (see [this example](http://hortonworks.com/hadoop-tutorial/how-to-use-excel-2013-to-access-hadoop-data/)).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what version of hadoop you're running, but you could try this from hortonworks

http://hortonworks.com/hadoop-tutorial/how-to-use-excel-2013-to-access-hadoop-data/

Answer (score 0):

HDFS can stores Structured data,Semi structured and Unstructured data.

### examples for each type:

-**Structured data**:Database tables,Data from enterprise systems(ERP,CRM etc)

-**Semistructured data**:logs,xml files

-**Unstructured data**: images,videos,word docs,pdf files,text files.